# Allow a marker to be dragged only inside a particular country in Google Maps V3

Tags: php, google-maps

what i'm trying to do :

1. A draggable marker that allowed to move over one country only.
2. After drag ends the location shows up in an input text.

INFO : locking the marker to one country works, but not perfectly , when i move the marker many times quickly even over that allowed country. it goes back to its position which should happens just over the other countries .

each part of the 2 required things work separately, when they are combined together as the following code , they don't work. the issue must be with the (dragend) listener but i can't find what it is.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<script>


var map = null;
var marker = null;
var country = 'DE';  

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').value = str;
}    

function initialize() {
  var startDragPosition = null;
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8,10.3),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.784084,9.181635),
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  var myGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragstart',function(event) {

    startDragPosition = marker.getPosition();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
    myGeocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(responses,results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[1]) {
        var countryMarker = addresComponent('country', results[1], true);
        if (country != countryMarker) {
          marker.setPosition(startDragPosition);
        }
       }
      else {
        marker.setPosition(startDragPosition);
      }
       if (responses && responses.length > 0) 
        {
          updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
        } 
        else 
       {
          updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
       }
    });
  });
}

function addresComponent(type, geocodeResponse, shortName) {
  for(var i=0; i < geocodeResponse.address_components.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < geocodeResponse.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
      if (geocodeResponse.address_components[i].types[j] == type) {
        if (shortName) {
          return geocodeResponse.address_components[i].short_name;
        }
        else {
          return geocodeResponse.address_components[i].long_name;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return '';
}
</script>
<style>
#map-canvas {
  height:400px;
}
</style>
<input type="text" id="address">
```

Comment: Do you think you could create a more descriptive title?

Comment: maybe , but it's not just one issue . so I've tried to be specific with the first two lines instead

Comment: @Konzept You should not edit out important information from the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general problem is at the callback of myGeocoder.geocode(). The function returns only two variables - responses and status. So the code below should work.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
    myGeocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(responses,status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && responses[0]) {
            var countryMarker = addresComponent('country', responses[0], true);
            if (country != countryMarker) {
                marker.setPosition(startDragPosition);
            }
        } else {
            marker.setPosition(startDragPosition);
        }
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
            updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
            updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
        }
    });
});
```

There are two reasons why moving the marker many times quickly can break the code.

1. The geocode() function is asynchronous, so if you create number of
   callbacks successively within short intervals, the completion order
   can be different than the creation order.
2. Google geocoder has a rate
   limit. If you do too many queries too quickly it will stop working.

Both problems can be solved restructuring the code into something like this. (note: This part of the code uses jquery so you may have to include that as well.)

```
//wrap the geocoder in a function.
function geocode (marker,country) {
    myGeocoder.geocode('query', function(){ ... } ); 
}

// call the geocoder with a timeout and clear the timeout everytime the geocoder is called again.
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
    clearTimeout($.data(marker,'timer'));
    $(marker).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){geocode(marker,country)}, 1000));

});
```

The above approach will make sure, no matter how fast you move the marker, the geocode functions are triggered only with a minimum gap between them (1000ms in the above case).

Comment: It is happening because myGeocoder.geocode() is asynchronous and has different execution times (since it has to query google servers). To remove this problem, you need to wrap the geocode as a function and set a timeOut for executing the function on 'dragend' and cancel the timeOut if a new 'dragend' happens before that time. I'll update the answer with a code example.

Comment: still happens, Is there another possible cause ?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with geocoder api's rate limit since the failed moves within Germany have null responses from the geocoder function.  Check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits